# what is the fastest grid components for asp.net mvc applications

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, grid

i have been looking at [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs), [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx).

does anyone have any performance metric comparisons or have any other alternative that they think is faster.

Comment: Your comparing a javascript only grid with one with MVC hooks...  Apples to Raisins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the telerik MVC extensions. The grid is very easy to use and support all the various paging mechanisms. You may find that will do what you're after, combined with a bit of behind-the-scenes custom paging.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/).  I've not had any performance issues with it and it's quite straightforward to use.

Answer (score -1):

Ok - I just built a quick and dirty version of the datatables and the jqgrid - loaded 1000 rows of data from an sql database and performed console.time tests in firebug.

The results where surprisingly similar with datatables barely edging out jqgrid in some situations - not enough to choose one over the other purely on performance (imo).